# laravel - how to check if sub sub sub relation exists

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

My controller is receiving an AgentId

```
public function save(Int $agent_id, Request $request)
```

So now I need to check if current user has permission to handle this agent_id.

The problem is that they are not directly connect with a relation.

The path between these models is:

```
User -> hasMany Workspace -> hasMany Inventory -> hasOne Agent
```

So the question is: is there an easier/cleaner way to check if the User has connection with this Agent?

What I'm trying so far is to loop all items for each relation level.

Comment: There is no native support. You can use 3rd party https://github.com/staudenmeir/eloquent-has-many-deep or you can use join method to get User data from Agent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Agent` model has a relation with a `User`, because you can't create a child table row without its parent data. You can reach User table with join method, like this :

```
$q = Agent::select('agents.*')
    ->where('id', $agent_id)
    ->join('inventories', 'inventories.id', '=', 'agents.inventory_id')
    ->join('workspaces', 'workspaces.id', '=', 'inventories.workspace_id')
    ->join('users', 'users.id', '=', 'workspaces.workspace_id')
    ->get();
```